# Laravel add new record in database returns error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, token

I am trying to add a new cart when you click a button with ajax.My code below:

1) Button

```
<a class="checkout-button">checkout</a>
```

2) Ajax

```
$('.checkout-button').on('click', function(){
  var url = '{{route('postcheckout')}}';
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : url,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
    data : {'user_id' : 5},
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

console.log and data used for test.

3) Route

```
Route::post('/checout',[
    'uses' => 'checkoutController@insertCart',
    'as' => 'postcheckout'
]);
```

4) Controller

```
Use App\delivery_cart;

public function insertCart(Request $request){               
  $user_id = $request['user_id'];
  $cart = new delivery_cart;
  $cart->user_id = $user_id;
  $cart->save();
}
```

Database has 2 columns - `cart_id` (primary,ai) and `user_id`.

When I am trying to insert new record I get an error 500 (internal server error which says : `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. However when I read from database it works. I found similar questions and I think that something going wrong with token, but I can't solve the problem.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: hi .. are you sure you only visit the route via `$_POST` method? I mean maybe haven't you redirect in that route in `$_GET` method just asking

Comment: this route has both get and post,but i tried with a different route with only post method and it didn't work.

Comment: I see,, it because you did not include `$_GET` into your routes change it to `Route::any(array('post','get'),'/checout',[
    'uses' => 'checkoutController@insertCart',
    'as' => 'postcheckout'
    ]);` or just add `Route::get('/checout',[
    'uses' => 'checkoutController@insertCart',
    'as' => 'postcheckout'
    ]);`

Comment: It works!But why i have to use get method too ?

Comment: you can just use `any(array('post','get'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It generate that error because that route don't have a `get` method in to your routes

to solve that you must register that method into your routes.

change your routes

from

```
Route::post('/checout',[
    'uses' => 'checkoutController@insertCart',
    'as' => 'postcheckout'
    ]);
```

to

```
Route::any(array('post','get'),'/checout',[
    'uses' => 'checkoutController@insertCart',
    'as' => 'postcheckout'
    ]);
```

or you can just add

```
Route::get('/checout',[
    'uses' => 'checkoutController@insertCart',
    'as' => 'postcheckout'
    ]);
```

Comment: Why i have to use get method?

Comment: @andrian because you use that route in `get` method also that's the rule of laravel, you must register every method you use into your routes

Comment: yes but i use checkout route only for post.That is what i dont understand.I only post with ajax in that route.Why i need get route too?

Comment: hi. try checking the network F12 and check the method request if it is really a `post` method